# select value from child jsp to parent using spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a parent jsp.

```
  <span> Operator</span>
  <form:select path="type" name="type" id="type" onChange="SelectType();">
  <form:option value="Select type">Select type</form:option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

When the type is selected, it will display a pop up window based on the option selected using the javascript function selectType();

selectType()

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function SelectType() 
 {
    var opr = document.getElementById("type").value;
    window.open("vehicle?type=" + opr, "win1", 'width=500,height=300,status');
 }
 </script>
```

The popup window contains some specs regarding the vehicle type that are displayed from the database..

The window jsp is..

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="top" varStatus="loop">
<tr>
   <td width=25%><c:out value="${top.name}" /></td>
   <td width=25%><c:out value="${top.price}" /></td>
   <td width=15%><c:out value="${top.engine}" /></td>
</c:forEach>
```

The popup jsp displays a list form the database. Now I need to select a particular row and the price value of that row should be passed to a text box in the parent jsp.
I tried writing a javascript in child jsp like this..

```
function showSelected(){

var i=document.getElementById("child_field_id").value;
opener.document.form.parent_name_id.value = i;
opener.document.form.submit();
window.close();    
}
```

but it didn't work..

Comment: .."but it didn't work.." means? what happened?

Comment: it is not selecting that field..

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('parent_name_id').value="Value changed..."
```